# AssertionError: Duplicate registrations for type 'experimentalOptimizer' using keras and tensorflow, randomly occurs between extecutions

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras, resnet

I randomly developed this error between executing my program and it working fine and the next time i tried to execute it. No idea what has happened since i have not touched either installs of tensorflow or keras. i'm completely clueless.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Conv2D' from 'keras.layers' (unknown
> location)

Source code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, AveragePooling2D, Input, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
import scipy
import os
import random
import gc
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from zipfile import ZipFile
import glob
#Checking corrupt images 2nd method.
import PIL
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import UnidentifiedImageError
path = Path("/com.docker.devenvironments.code/fer2013/trainimgs").rglob("*.jpg")
for img_p in path:
    try:
        img = PIL.Image.open(img_p)
    except PIL.UnidentifiedImageError:
            print(img_p)
training = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
testing = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

traindata = training.flow_from_directory('/com.docker.devenvironments.code/fer2013/trainimgs',
target_size=(48,48),
batch_size=64,
color_mode='rgb',
class_mode='categorical')

testdata = testing.flow_from_directory('/com.docker.devenvironments.code/fer2013/testimgs',
target_size=(48,48),
batch_size=64,
color_mode='rgb',
class_mode='categorical')
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=(48,48,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
#ResNet model with additional convolutional layers.
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(48,48,3), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))

#model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model_info = model.fit(traindata,epochs=30,validation_data=testdata)


#base_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentrophy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model_info = base_model.fit(traindata, steps_per_epoch=449,epochs=100,validation_data=testdata,validation_steps=112)

#model.save('ResNet50_Improved')
#new = tf.keras.models.load_model('ResNet50_Improved')
#new.evaluate()
#model.summary()

#ResNet model without any additional layers.
#resnet = Sequential()
#resnet.add(base_model)
#resnet.add(Flatten())
#resnet.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
#resnet.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
#resnet.summary()

#resnet.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#resnet.fit(traindata,epochs=30,validation_data=testdata)
```

Comment: Latest Keras version is compatible with Tensorflow. Replace Keras with `Tensorflow.keras`. Hence use from `tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, AveragePooling2D, Input, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense, Dropout`. Thanks!